# Regex to get amount from sentence not working for one scenario

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex.  I need to extract amount from sentence:

The watches are INR **2,550** Only
Kidswear under INR **399.59** Only
Cricket bat INR**590** Only

I have created a regex which extracts the first two amounts and tried for 3rd one but still it is not working. Can someone please help.

My Regex - `(?i)\\b(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word boundary at the beginning prevents the INR590 from matching. But if you omit that word boundary, you would match digits at a lot more places.

For the example string, you could make the pattern a bit more specific instead and add a word boundary at the end of the pattern.

```
(?i)\bINR\h*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0zTQlh/1)

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?i)\\bINR\\h*(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?)\\b";
```

You could also for example assert that what is directly to the left is either a space or another allowed character:

```
(?<=\h|[A-Z])\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2qa0uO/1)

Answer (score 0):

`/\s*INR\s*(\d+[,.]{0,1}\d+)/g`

\s* match any number of whitespace character.

INR match "INR"

\d+ match any number

[,.]{0,1}\d+ match between 0 comma or point followed by a number.

(\d+[,.]{0,1}\d+) match group number such as "10", "10.1", "10,1".
And it's between bracket, you can get exactly the data between.

For greater number wrote as this model:
1.000.000,00
Replace (\d+[,.]{0,1}\d+) by (\d+(.\d+)*([,.]{0,1}\d+))

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression matches representations of dollar values that satisfy the conventional required format:

```
(?<=\bINR ?)(?:[1-9]\d{1,2}|\d)(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?(?![\d.,])
```

[Java 8 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jhjrtg/1)

The link tests the following strings.

```
The watches are INR 2,550 Kidswear under INR 2,399.59 Cricket bat INR590
                    ^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^                ^^^
Cement mixers are INR 25,34,128 B767 are INR 23,401,798,261.35
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Cough drops are INR 3.241 Bubble gum is INR 01.23
```

The four matches are indicated by the party hats. `25,34,128` was rejected because there are other than three digits between each successive pair of commas, `3.241` was passed over because it has other than two digits to the right of the decimal point and `01.23` failed the cut because of the leading zero.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=         # begin positive lookbehind
  \bINR ?    # match a word break followed by 'INR'
)            # end positive lookbehind
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  [1-9]      # match a digit other than 0
  \d{1,2}    # match 1 or 2 digits
  |          # or
  \d         # match 1 digit
)            # end non-capture group
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  ,\d{3}     # match ',' followed by 3 digits
)*           # end non-capture group and execute it 0 or more times
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  \.\d{2}    # match '.' then  2 digits
)?           # end non-capture group and execute it 0 or 1 times
(?!          # begin negative lookahead
  [\d.,]     # match a digit, '.' or ','
)            # end negative lookahead
```

I don't know Java but was a bit surprised to find that the lookbehind (`(?<=\bINR ?)`) could contain an optional character (a space). If a version of Java is used that does not support that, the lookbehind could be replaced with the following:

```
(?:(?<=\bINR )|(?<=\bINR))
```